# Get values from child XML nodes having same node name in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I've below XML

```
<Root>
<field/>
<field/>
<field>
    <label>
        Have you invested before
    </label>
    <value>
        No
    </value>
    <label>
        Are you looking to Invest in the next 6 months
    </label>
    <value>
        Maybe
    </value>
</field>
<field>
    <label>
        What Investments are you interested in
    </label>
    <value>
        Carbon Credits, Green Investments
    </value>
</field>
<field>
    <label>
        How much are you looking to invest
    </label>
    <value>
        £250,000+
    </value>
</field>
```

And from this i need to render it as `HTML` like as below.

```
Have you invested before: No
Are you looking to invest in the next 6 months: Maybe
What investments are you interested in: Carbon Credits, Green Investments
How much are you looking to invest: £250,000+
```

Currently it's output is :

```
:
:     
Have you invested beforeAre you looking to Invest in the next 6 months: YesMaybe
What Investments are you interested in:  Carbon Credits, Green Investments
How much are you looking to invest:    £250,000+
```

I'm using below `jquery` but its not producing the output i'm expecting.

```
$(data).find('field').each(function (index, element) {
        debugger;
        //if (field.find('label').length > 0) {
        var field = $(element)
        if (field.find('label').length > 1) {

            var confirmationNumbers = $(field).find("label").map(function () {
                //debugger;
                list.append('<dt>' + label + ': </dt>').append('<dd>' + value + '</dd>');
                return $(this).text();
            });                
            //var label = field.find('label').text()
            //var value = field.find('value').text()
            //list.append('<dt>' + label + ': </dt>').append('<dd>' + value + '</dd>');
        }
        else {
            var label = field.find('label').text()
            var value = field.find('value').text()
            list.append('<dt>' + label + ': </dt>').append('<dd>' + value + '</dd>');
        }
        //}            
    });
```

What i'm doing wrong..

Comment: Try using jQuery Templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(data).find('field label').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    list.append('<dt>' + $this.text() + ': </dt>').append('<dd>' + $this.text().val() + '</dd>');
})
```

Try this for IE

```
$(data).find('field label').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    list.append('<div><span>' + $this.text() + '</span><span>'
            + $this.text().val() + '</span></div>');
})
```

Comment: @MayankPathak try using a simple `ul` and `li`

Comment: it works with `dt` and `dd` as well...Problem was with `XML`. I just parsed it using `$.parseXML()` and worked with your code...Many thanks Arun..You provided exact solution mate.. :)